# Moving Up and Down list objects

Tags: jquery

Im creating a simple list (header + text under). These section will looks like a FAQ.

I would like to make moving up and down objects on list. When I click last object its goes up to top etc.

Tried with `rollUp();` but was not work. How I can make that?

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/oxhqpes9/

```
$(function(){

  $('.opis').hide();


  $('li .nazwa').click(function(){
      $('.opis').hide();
      $(this).nextAll('.opis:first').toggle();
  });


});
```

Comment: And if you click the one before last? Does it also move to the top? Or you are trying to make an accordion effect?

Comment: Yes, all of list item have to go top after click. Its have to be like active effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to prepend currently clicked item to its parent container `ul`:

```
var $ul = $('ul');

$('.opis').hide();

$('li .nazwa').click(function () {
    $('.opis').hide();
    $(this).nextAll('.opis:first').toggle();
    $(this).parent().prependTo($ul);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oxhqpes9/2/

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right you should use `slideToggle`

```
 $('li .nazwa').click(function(){
    $('.opis').slideUp();
    $(this).nextAll('.opis:first').slideToggle();
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oxhqpes9/1/)